# How mark the current working directory as stable branch using Tortoise HG and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I got a project with a single commit (default), how I could mark this as the stable branch?

What I'm looking is keep this as the stable version and start new changes with the default branch.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer. Hg supports tagging, which can be used to identify a specific point in time (AKA a release). It is covered in the Red Bean Book in [Chapter 8. Managing releases and branchy development](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html).

As far as *forcing* people to be up-to-date and branching off latest-stable, that's more of a group discipline / workflow problem. Years ago at Xerox (late 70's) our own manager (who shall remain nameless to protect the guilty) violated the group check-in / check-out rules to the point where *we changed the master password* on the directory. He was only allowed to check out a file with someone else acting as the adult.